# Cassandra log shows "Writing large partition *** to sstable" WARN even after dropping them

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

How to get rid of warnings being logged even after dropping large paritions.

```
[CompactionExecutor:2939] BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition *** to sstable
```

I did nodetool repair to eliminate dropped rows and also changed `gc_grace_seconds` to 1 hrs and ran repair.

Do i need to run any specific jobs to make sure they gets dropped from SSTables?
Cassandra version 3.11

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

I found it working by running "nodetool garbagecollect" which actually removing deleted rows from sstables.

Answer (score 0):

I run cassandra reaper jobs http://cassandra-reaper.io/ or https://docs.k8ssandra.io/components/reaper/ on scheduled basis to elevate any problems. We have a streaming application that results in large writes to cassandra